# zend 2 form filters not working

Tags: forms, filter, zend-framework2, validation

I'm trying to use some Zend\Filter with forms to ensure that my data is correctly formatted.
I have a typical input (text) named 'parent_id' which I apply some filters :

```
'filters' => array(
    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\Int'),
    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\Null', 'options' => array('type' => \Zend\Filter\Null::TYPE_INTEGER)),
),
```

After that, I use a custom validator on another field which needs to check the 'parent_id' value via the $context.

```
public function isValid($value, $context = null) {
        var_dump($context);
}
```

When I dump the var $context, I get this:

```
array(2) {
    ["parent_id"]=> string(0) ""
    ["target_id"]=> string(1) "1"
}
```

I checked the execution order and my filters are running before the validator, so why I don't get :
`["parent_id"]=> NULL OR ["parent_id"]=> INT(something)` ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Okay, I did further tests:

 - When I grab the data from my form ($form->getData()), after the $form->isValid(), my data is correctly set and 'parent_id' = NULL OR INT()

So why I can't get my formatted values in my validators ????

Comment: The data passed as context to validators is always raw data, no way around that without some re-writing of the framework. It's simple enough to test is_numeric against the raw value and cast as int or set null accordingly. `$parentId = is_numeric($context['parent_id']) ? (int) $context['parent_id'] : null;` (I do understand where you're coming from with the question though, there is some redundancy caused by this)

Comment: @Crisp Ofc there is some redundancy and for complex filters, I have to apply them again....... in my validator......

Comment: Yeah, seems like a candidate for a feature request, I can see use cases for both raw and filtered input in validator context. Not sure it's something we'll see in ZF2 though, but the discussion is under way on how ZF3s should work and might be worth mentioning -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/4772

Comment: @Crisp I did a pull request on Github : https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/6341

I don't know if it will be accepted because I threw away/replaced the raw values method :D

Thanks for your help.